# Coldbox module name collision with handler package

Tags: module, coldfusion, coldbox

I have a ColdBox monolith we will be migrating into modules.  The directory structure is

```
/myapp
  /handlers
    /admin
      person.cfc
      product.cfc
    /user
      cart.cfc
    global.cfc
    main.cfc
```

I'm trying to load an external module that is structured like

```
/otherRepositoryRoot
  /myappModules
    /admin
      /handlers
      /models
      /views
      ModuleConfig.cfc
    /user
      /handlers
      /models
      /views
      ModuleConfig.cfc
```

Pretty standard.  We have lots more in the `/admin` and `/user` handlers folders; this is just a sample.

We need `/myapp/admin/product/index` to still run from the monolith, but move the `person.cfc` handler to `.../myappModules/admin/handlers/`.

The problem is when I specify `this.entryPoint = "/admin";` in the admin `ModuleConfig.cfc` file, I try to visit `/myapp/admin/person/index` in the browser and get stuck in a redirect loop.

Is there a way for the CB routes to look in the host application's `/handlers` first and fall back to loaded modules?  (or try modules first and fall back to `/handlers`?)

*note: the modules will be in an external location since they will be shared by other applications and are being placed in a separate repo.  Not sure if that makes any difference as far as naming since I think the same issue would exist even if we installed them from the other repo in `/modules`*